# How to connect Samsung phone to Soniq Smart TV via bluetooth without the remote?

Tags: samsung, remote-control

I have Samsung Galaxy A11 and Soniq Smart TV which uses [Soniq QT166 remote](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1400187/Soniq-Qt166.html). Currently, I don't have the remote. I am trying to download a remote on my phone as a replacement. However, I can't connect the phone to the TV without the remote.

Can I connect a Soniq QT166 remote to my Samsung Galaxy A11? Without a remote, I don't know how to connect to Bluetooth via phone to TV.

Comment: I'm sorry .. is that more accurate  I cannot connect to blue tooth via phone to tv with out remote

Comment: Please edit your question and reformulate it completely including title. And please don't forget to exactly specify (device name and version, running OS; ..) the involved devices.

Comment: How to connect  to soniq tv using blue tooth on my Samsung  a11

Comment: I am trying  to download the remote on my phone as I don't have one

Comment: Hi, I've tried to edit and incorporate the details from the comments. Hopefully, I'm not mistaken in interpreting the issue. Consider [edit]ing to add more context and details though to increase the chance for proper solutions.

Comment: Also, since I found the manual that tells about the pairing process to the RF dongle for the TV remote, I'm worried that the Android phone also needs to do the same pairing process to be considered as a "remote", and this might be the biggest problem without knowing how it's done...

Answer (score 0):

There are many apps available on Google Play Store, out of those, these are two.

- If your phone has IR, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.tv.remote.control.sony.remote.control
- If your phone does not have IR, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tv.remote